# Django template and Math expression for dynamic content

Tags: django, templates, latex, sympy, mathjax

How do you set dynamic content passed from view to template to use mathjax or Latex. To be more precise in the terminal if 2*sqrt(2) would be displayed as 2√2 by pprint function. But in the django template it outputs as 2*sqrt(2) and not 2√2?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out in case anyone else runs into the same problem here's is the working solution. I used AsciiMath Input as the input format in mathjax that incorporates [ASCIIMathML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AsciiMath).

In the base.html add the following scripts:

```
<script>
  MathJax = {
    loader: {load: ['input/asciimath', 'output/chtml']}
  }
</script>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/startup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js">
```

and remember to enclose the dynamic text by back-ticks”, i.e., `...` So in the django-admin you can simply enter sqrt(50) as ` sqrt(50) ` or ` x^2 ` and the dynamic content which is passed from view to the template, in the template you surround {{e1}} by back-ticks

### ` {{ e1 }} `

instead of 
    {{ e1 }} 
where e1 is the dynamic content. So if e1 which was earlier displayed in plain text as 2*sqrt(2) will now be displyed as 2√2.

For more details: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/asciimath.html#asciimath-support